# Parse XML in vb.net (Multiple Nodes?)

Tags: xml, vb.net

```
Dim page As XElement = _
<response>
    <results>
        <result>
            <status>OK</status>
            <number>phonenumberhere</number>
            <wless>y</wless>
            <carrier_name>ATT Mobility</carrier_name>
            <sms_address>phonenumberhere@txt.att.net</sms_address>
            <mms_address>phonenumberhere@mms.att.net</mms_address>
        </result>
    </results>
</response>

Me.addr = page.Element("sms_address").Value
```

It crashes on `Me.addr = page.Element("sms_address").Value`
I need to store the sms_address as a string.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Dim page As XElement = <response><results><result><status>OK</status><number>phonenumberhere</number><wless>y</wless><carrier_name>ATT Mobility</carrier_name><sms_address>phonenumberhere@txt.att.net</sms_address><mms_address>phonenumberhere@mms.att.net</mms_address></result></results></response>
Me.addr = page.Element("results") _
              .Element("result") _
              .Element("sms_address").Value
```

The element you were looking for is not at the top, so page.Element("sms_address") won't find it.

Alternatively, since you're lucky enough to be using VB.NET, you can use

```
page...<sms_address>.Value
```

or

```
page.<results>.<result>.<sms_address>.Value
```

Comment: I get an error Leading '.' or '!' can only appear inside a 'With' statement.

Comment: Add line continuation characters to the end of each broken line. Also the first `.Element("response")` is wrong. Remove that.

Comment: @Enigmativity: fixed, I think. My Visual Studio is broken right now, so I can't test it. And I thought they had gotten rid of the need for line continuations. Would it have worked if I broke the line _after_ the `.`?

Comment: @JohnSaunders - They got rid of most of the cases where you needed a line continuation. Now it's real annoying, not just annoying. And yes, if you did the `.` at the end of the line you wouldn't need the line continuations, but that just makes it hard to read.